# Django doesn't remember authenticated user

Tags: django, django-views

I have got a simple login function.

```
def login(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

And in my template, I use `if` statement to show some block only for authenticated users:

```
{% if username %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="span6">Welcome!<strong> {{ username }}</strong></div>
{% endif %}
```

But when I am successfully logined, this block is not showed. I guess that the problem with `redirect('/')`. If it's so, I don't understand then: when I redirect to main page, then user is logged out?
For main page I use next view:

```
def index(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'index.html', args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `user` context variable to display the user's name.  And the [`is_authenticated()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) method of the user instance should be used to determine the logged users from anonymous:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome! <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add args to render call? I'm doing it for csrf. As I know, render automatically contains RequestContext, but my question is wheter RequestContext contains csrf(request)?

Comment: Third argument of the `render()` shortcut is optional so you can safely omit it: `render(request, 'index.html')`. `RequestContext` will contain valid CSRF data.